# File isn't written to after program runs

Tags: java, save, fileoutputstream, jgrasp

So i'm trying to write to a file to use as a save point to access later, but i cant actually get it to write to the file. I'm trying to save the components of a class to access next time I open and run the program, by writing a string with the PIV's to the file as a save method and by using a scanner to search for tags at the beginning of each line to access later. My code so far though, will not actually write to the file. It compiles and runs fine, but the file shows being unchanged after the program runs.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
   {
      File f = new File("SaveFile");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
      String save = new String();
         while(sc.hasNextLine())
         {
                save=sc.nextLine();
         }
      byte buf[]=save.getBytes();
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
      for(int i=0;i<buf.length;i++) 
        fos.write(buf[i]);
      if(fos != null)
      {
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
      }
   }
```

If anyone has a way to fix the code or even a better idea for saving please let me know, thanks

Comment: Side note: you want to read about try-with-resources; you don't need that manual closing anymore. There is also no point in flushing before closing (you only call flush manually when 'writing' is supposed to take a long time; and you have pressing reasons to make sure that content is forced to be written).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing `save` value in every single `nextLine`.
Change this line:

```
save = sc.nextLine();
```

to this one:

```
save += sc.nextLine();
```

Also, it's better to use a `FileWriter` when you are writing `String` to a file.
And because String is `immutable`, it will be a slow procedure. Consider using `StringBuilder` or `CharBuffer` instead of simple solution which I mentioned above.
Look at code included below:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        File f = new File("SaveFile");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            builder.append(sc.nextLine() + "\n");
        }
        String save = builder.toString();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f);
        writer.write(save);
        writer.close();
    }
```

Also `close()` implicitly calls `flush()`.

Comment: Side note: although not too important; but using a string for this is just bad. That is what StringBuilder should be used for ...

Comment: While we are being so diligent ... depending on the OS you are running on, using plain `\n` for "new line" might be OK, doing the job, or plain wrong ;-)